# Please complete this expression

Tags: metaphysics, philosophy-of-religion

Longtime ago I heard someone say this, I need to know the correct wording and source of this expression. The basic idea is expression of how human society has changed over the last few hundred years. It says that the paradigm shift is,

1. From emphasis on afterlife to our current life
2. From emphasis on soul to body
3. From metaphysical to physical???

Can someone correct mistake in 3rd point and also tell me who mentioned these 3 points in explanation of the nature modern world please?

Comment: "In the old days, car manuals told you how to adjust your valves. Now they tell you not to drink the battery water."

Comment: "metaphysics" "philosophy-of-religion" ???